# Ionic 3 game building, meta viewport tag settings for android?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, viewport

I am building a html/javascript side scroller game with Ionic framework.
Currently I am working to get it working on desktop browsers and android, but later I will also make it work on ios...

Currently my problem is that I have the game area element width set to 1024px, and I want have it scale on any device full width on any orientation.

The game works fine on browsers, but when building it to android, it shows a zoomed in view, and zooming is disabled completely.

I have been searching days now for a solution...

I have tried to set the viewport meta tag, but it only allows me to zoom in even further.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=0.1, maximum-scale=2, user-scalable=no">
```

I have played around a lot with the options, like "width=1024", "initial-scale=0.5", "user-scalable=yes" and even "target-densitydpi=device-dpi", nothing but initial-scale=1 or larger seems to even do anything.

I have also tried to find out how to scale the viewport in code to fit the content in different ways.

I tried adding appView.setInitialScale(0) to MainActivity.java, but there is no appView in Ionic 3 any more.

I tried to add EnableViewportScale in the Config.xml, but that is only for ios, no effect on android.

I tried to use setUseWideViewPort(), but could not get android.webkit imported to the MainActivity.java in my project.

I looked at ViewControllers, but could not find any decent tutorial for beginners.

The ion-scroll element does not seem to have any zooming capabilities any more.

I found some solutions that use android:layout_width="fill_parent" options in a file called BrowserLayout.xml, but there is no such file in Ionic 3.

I tried to scale my content to the screen width with css zoom, but that messes up the touch event coordinates i use.

I have now ran out of ideas on how to do this, so I am asking for help.
What would be the correct way to scale the viewport?